# How to create reminder/countdown using datetime module

Tags: python, datetime

So now I'm working to make reminder or countdown in Python. I've code my own but I don't think this is the answer what I want. I want to take user input then append it to list, and then checking if is it the time or not. If it's the time it will remind user, if not just pass it. The code stops here, I'm stuck

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

deadline_list = []

format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
time_now = datetime.now()
result = time_now.strftime(format)

deadline = input('Enter deadline (YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS): ')
deadline_list.append(deadline)

while True:
  for deadlines in deadline_list:
    if deadlines ==  result:
        print("TImes end")
        break
    else:
        print("Still time")
```

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete. You need to compare the `deadline` with the current time somewhere

Comment: At first you must validate user input by your datetime definition. As second you must declare infinity loop function where you will take an input from user. Your deadline_list must be as example as a global variable. After all you must run your loop function just only after checkinf what your programm has been runned from __main__ module.

Comment: Lemme edit and complete my code, wait for update

Comment: I forgot one last important thing - listen user input for ctrl+c... In other case escape from your program will likely charmed kung-fu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hopfully. This can help U, Bros

```
import time

# define the countdown function.

def countdown(t):
    while t:
        mins, secs = divmod(t, 60)
        timer = '{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mins, secs)
        print(timer, end="\r")
        time.sleep(1)
        t -= 1  # t = t-1

    print('Time End!!')


# input time in seconds
t = input("Enter the time in seconds: ")

# function call
countdown(int(t))
```

###### For more information: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-countdown-timer-using-python/

Comment: not what i want, i mean this code I want to put in my application and run in at server. in will store the information of `deadline` and remind user if it's already deadline

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).